# Break a grouped dataframe into separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to take a dataframe that has been grouped and create separate dataframes for each respective group.

I'm using a list comprehension to slice a pandas dataframe using values in a list `names_list` and then assigning the result to variables of the same name. However, the values in `names_list` don't always appear in my dataframe and which one will not be in the dataframe is completely random. How can I make this work and return only the variables that actually appear?

What I tried:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

names_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [df.loc[idx[x,:],:] for x in names_list]
```

The above returns a KeyError whenever a value doesn't exist in the dataframe.

Also tried:

```
def split_df(data):
    try:
        a = [df.loc[idx[x,:],:] for x in data]
    except KeyError:
        a = None
    return a


names_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [x for x in names_list]
name_vars = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

name_vars_2 = []
for var, val in zip(name_vars,names_list):
    var = split_df(val)
    if var is None:
        continue
    else:
        name_vars_2.append(var)
```

This approach only returns a list of None for each value.

My desired result is a list of variables with the respective slice of the dataframe assigned to each variable.

Comment: "I'm using a list comprehension to slice a pandas dataframe using values in a list names_list and then assigning the result to variables of the same name." I just don't understand the use-case. Surely this is the handiwork of an XY problem?

Comment: There is no use case for this. Use `groupby`, optionally with `dict` if you want a variable number of variables. This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain your *underlying* issue and we may be able to help.

Comment: I've already performed a groupby on the main dataframe. What I'd like to do is now split the main dataframe into separate dataframes for each group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(10), B=[*'aabbccddee']))
```

---

#### `dict`

Store them in a dictionary rather than named variables

```
d = dict((*df.groupby('B'),))
```

---

```
d['a']

   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  a
```

---

```
d['d']

   A  B
6  6  d
7  7  d
```

---

#### NOT RECOMMENDED!

But for your education.  You can update the `locals()` dictionary.
This is bad because dynamically polluting the name space will lead to many hard to track bugs.
In fact it isn't guaranteed to do anything.

[**Per Docs**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note**: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Disclaimers out of the way, this is how you can do it:

```
locals().update(dict((*df.groupby('B'),)))
```

Then access the named variables

```
a

   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  a
```

---

```
d

   A  B
6  6  d
7  7  d
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data itself, the following should work.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

n0, n1 = 8, 3
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(ascii_lowercase[:n0]),
                                   list(ascii_uppercase[:n1])])
columns = ['foo', 'bar']
arr = np.arange(n0*n1*len(columns)).reshape((len(midx),len(columns)))
all_df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=midx, columns=columns)
sub_df = all_df.query('foo < 12 or foo > 16').query('foo < 42')
vals = lambda df, idx, l: {c: df.loc[idx[c, :], :] for c in l}
```

Rather than explicitly assigning the variables, use a dictionary and see the results as they would appear for the whole dataset and one with a chunk removed.

```
all_vals = vals(all_df, pd.IndexSlice, list(ascii_lowercase[:n0]))
sub_vals = vals(sub_df, pd.IndexSlice, list(ascii_lowercase[:n0]))
```

and for example,

```
>>> all_vals['a']
     foo  bar
a A    0    1
  B    2    3
  C    4    5

>>> sub_vals['a']
     foo  bar
a A    0    1
  B    2    3
  C    4    5
```

but,

```
>>> all_vals['c']
     foo  bar
c A   12   13
  B   14   15
  C   16   17

>>> sub_vals['c']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [foo, bar]
Index: []
```

Finally you might filter the comprehension with something like `[... for x in lst if x in df.index.levels[0].values]` and possibly store the values in a `collections.defaultdict`  initialized as you'd like.